# Cannot figure out why this function returns zero

Tags: c++, return

I have been at this for more than an hour and I still can't figure out why this function returns 0.

Hopefully an extra pair of eyes can help me figure out what is going wrong.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int power(int x, int y, int p)
{
    // cout << x << " " << y << " " << p << " " << res << endl;
    if(x==0)
        return 0;
    if(y==0)
        return 0;

    long res = 1;
    if(y%2 == 0){
        res = power(x, y/2, p);
        res = (res*res)%p;
    }
    else{
        res = x%p;
        res = (res*power(x, y-1, p) % p) % p;
    }
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << p << " " << res << endl;
    return int((res+p)%p);
}

int main() {
    cout << power(2, 100000, 1000000007);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `pr` here `cout << pr(2, 100000, 1000000007);` ? You meant for `cout << power(2, 100000, 1000000007);` ?

Comment: There is no `pr` and main ends with `return 0`.

Comment: @Achal sorry, I had edited it before posting.

Comment: Its returning `1000000007 % 1000000007` which is `0`. Since it is recursion you need to try recursive calls on paper & find out. Also use [gdb](https://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html) to debug it.

Comment: Are you overflowing int? What happens when you change the type to double, and reduce the values?

Comment: Hint: what is the base case in your recursion? You can follow by hand what happens for `power(2, 1, 7)`, and in particular the recursive call.

Comment: @MarcGlisse understood!
Thanks. Can't believe I missed that. For anyone wondering, the if condition for y should return 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be changed:

```
if(y==0)
        return 1;
```